# Does Java compiler eliminate function calls from getters?

Tags: java, function, inline, compiler-optimization, getter

Can I be sure that

```
private int value;
public int getValue() { return value; }
```

is compiled by compiler in the same way as

```
public int Value;
```

in the terms of number of instructions and execution time? I mean do modern compilers trying to make functions "inline" (c++ term)?

Comment: A dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109995/do-getters-and-setters-impact-performance-in-c-d-java

Comment: BTW The JVM can inline up to two "virtual" methods, something a static compiler does not do.

Comment: What are virtual methods? From `C++` point of view, all methods in java are virtual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; the Java *compiler* will not change that.

However, the JITter probably will.

Comment: Indeed, the JIT optimizes it for you.

Comment: @Gilberto Won't the JIT only optimize it if it discovers a need to? I'm not comfortable asserting a JIT will always optimize a "simple" getter (less so a more complex on) given there are multiple implementations and environments.

Comment: @DaveNewton Programming in Java is an exercise of faith: you hope the GC will run, you hope the JIT will compile and optimize, you hope you write once and the program will run everywhere. Have faith, brother. ;-)

Comment: I was thinking JIT is a compiling too.